# Set id to EditText in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I’m getting some data from a **REST API** (json) from a wordpress.

With theses data, I’m creating some **EditText** and add the value of the API into the EditText. I want to set an ID so that two of the EditText that I’ve created can be used by each other (for a calcutation : price * quantity)

But when I'm trying to add an id, Android Studio says that it needs to be an **int** (not like we do in XML, is that the usual comportement ?).

```
val input = EditText(this)
input.id = id //dynamically equals 5
val test = findViewById<EditText>(5) //5 as ID is not working...
```

What am I missing on this ?

Comment: you are creating `EditText` but not adding it into layout . I think that might be the problem

Comment: Also in XML the id is a number. `@+id/myview` will map to the value `R.id.myview` which is of type int.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suppose you should be using `R.id.theid` which is an integer after `findViewById<EditText>` but that's just a numeric int which you're trying to add to `EditText`.

Comment: @Redman I'm adding it to the layout, just not showing this part. Markus could you explain more please ?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท if you're saying **findViewById<EditText>(R.id.5)** i tried, it's not working but it isn't giving error either

Comment: No. Not like that. I mean, it should have a int like `R.id.theidofedittext` which we refer that to the layout widget. But, adding it as only integer type will not absolutely work.

Comment: I see, but I what I need is to do this dynamically, how can I do this ? (maybe doing this by generating an xml ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your example:

```
val editText = EditText(this)
editText.id = 5
val test = findViewById<EditText>(5)
```

This doesn't work because '5' is not a valid id, because an id must be an hexadecimal int, and must be different from others views' id. So the better way to achieve your purpose is to do something like this:

```
val editText = EditText(this)
editText.id = View.generateViewId()
val test = findViewById<EditText>(editText.id)
```

According to the docs for `View.generateViewId()`:

> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

But I don't know why you need the "test" EditText, in this way you'll have 2 EditText object that refers to the same View.